# The laptops in the Turkish movie Recep İvedik 3 (2009)

Tags: identify-this-computer, identify-this-peripheral, laptop

I watched *Recep İvedik 3* as a kid and it had a story about laptops.

[In Clip 1, Recep broke Zeynep's laptop trying to kill a fly.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ibCoSpGnQs&t=1s)

[In Clip 2, he tried to buy a laptop from a Teknosa store but he didn't really have much money so he asked the salesman to get something from the rearmost spot in the warehouse for 375 liras (corresponding to 250 dollars in 2009's Turkey)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztT-ZJk0_OM)

[In Clip 3, he gifts "Pentium Core 2 Duo, 128 Kilobyte" laptop with what appears to be DC to AC pure sine wave power inverter. She comments how 80's it looks after Recep talked how it had handles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXNRNmZrQJE):

[image: Frame from the third clip, with both characters and the laptop visible]

I wondered about the laptop in clip 1 but was always more interested in the one in clip 3 and if it was really a power brick or they decided to pull up something big for comedic effect. I got gifted a Inspiron 1501 with not as big power brick but the owner joked about how it was "Koçaklı" referring to it's handles making me wonder when these Koçaks/Handles disappeared and really how old clip 1 and 3 laptop was.

Comment: By form factor, it looks like something from the early 1990s, or maybe indeed late 1980s, but the specific model eludes me. I wouldn’t be too surprised if it was something original to Turkey; compare <https://youtu.be/gydvSK4tW6c> (clearly not the same thing, but perhaps same manufacturer?).

Comment: Agree with the late 80s - early 90s. The lack of a built in pointing device (trackball, trackpad, etc) confirms that. It also appears to have a spot to put a paper F-key shortcut template above the keyboard (although I suppose it could be a sticker) which is pretty old fashioned and might be a clue to the identity. Confusingly though it does appear to have a "windows"/meta key (3 keys to the left of the space bar instead of 2) which is jarring with the other features. Maybe it could not be a real laptop but rather a prop made up of parts from different actual computers?

Comment: @mnem I'd imagine those three keys are Ctrl, Alt, and Fn. No need for a Windows key.

Comment: @ssokolow Ah, good point! I had forgotten all about laptop Fn keys.

Comment: The other laptop seems too new for this site, but it looks like Exper MS-1682, which is apparently a Turkey-exclusive brand of MSI. The layout of sockets on the sides of the laptop matches that model, at least.

Comment: @user3840170 ah this is the laptop I use alphacam on at work. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The laptop in clip 3 looks like a Commodore C286-LT, judging by the shape and placement of the hinge, the pattern on the top of the case, and the general fit of the look of everything with the laptop open. Judging by the looks it probably had a new black repaint of its outer case for film prop use.

That's its stock power brick there too, judging by its general look with the conspicuous space in between the two vents.

- [Computer History Museum (UK) entry](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/2222/Commodore-C286-LT-Portable/)
- [Vintage Computer Wiki page that includes some photos with the power brick](https://wiki.preterhuman.net/Commodore_C286-LT)

There are a number of different OEM versions of these early Commodore PC laptops -- though with different case industrial designs so they are distinctive looking -- and if you want to know them you can just look up the list from 3rd party suppliers of replacement battery packs for any of the models.

From https://www.energyplusbatteries.com/pf/5ed7/f61d4/P170AE_10LX-AGI-386SX20-NiCad-Battery-/ :

> This is a 10 cell Nickel Cadmium rechargeable battery pack designed to work in Commodore C286-LT, C386SX/LT, Everex Tempo LX, Tempo LX386SL, Tempo LX386SX, Sanyo MBC17NB, MBC18NB6H, Zeos 286, 386, 386/16, 386SX/20 series laptop and notebook computers.

Comment: While Dynabook J-3100SS isn't it, I'd say it (along with its cousin Toshiba T3100e) are probably where Commodore got a big helping of design ideas from.

Comment: This one seems highly likely! Though the still frame is rather blurry, one can clearly see that the label in the upper-right corner of the keyboard part starts with a ‘C’, so that also fits. And given that Commodore had a history of selling the same hardware in not necessarily perfectly-identical casing, perhaps the filmmakers didn’t even have to repaint it.

Comment: Good call, that's a better match than the Toshibas.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly has the look of a ~1990 Toshiba, like the T1000LE, T1200XE, or Dynabook J-3100SS, although none of those is an exact match. It's even got the card insert between the keyboard and the screen where you can write down notes on what the function keys do in your favorite app.

And the power brick for my Toshiba T1200 is about that bulky as well:

[image: Toshiba laptop power supply PA7485U, photo mine.]

Obviously Core 2 Duo has nothing to do with anything; that's a technology from 15-20 years later, and laptops from that era (even the rugged ones) didn't really look like what's in the photo.